# Join table is not updated in ManyToMany association in doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have tow entities `Slaplans` and `Slaholidays` and a join table `slaplans_slaholidays`.
After creating two `Slaholidays` objects, I persist them both, add them to the `Slaplans`  and flush. The problem is that only the `slaplans` and `slaholidays` tables are updated, but the join table isn't.

`Slaplans` Entity :

```
<?php
namespace ZC\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Slaplans
 *
 * @Table(name="slaplans")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\Slaplans")
 */
class Slaplans
{         
   /*
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Slaholidays",inversedBy="plans", cascade={"ALL"})
    * @JoinTable(name="slaplans_slaholidays",
    * joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="slaplanid" ,referencedColumnName="slaplanid")},
    * inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="slaholidayid" ,referencedColumnName="slaholidayid")})
    * }
     */
    private $holidays;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->holidays = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

public function getHolidays() {
    return $this->holidays;
}
public function setHolidays($holidays)
{
    $this->holidays=$holidays;

}
/*public function addHoliday($holiday) {

    $this->holidays[]=$holiday;
}*/
}
```

`Slaholidays` Entity:

```
<?php
namespace ZC\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Slaholidays
 *
 * @Table(name="slaholidays")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\Slaholidays")
 */
class Slaholidays
{
    /**
     * @var integer $slaholidayid
     *
     * @Column(name="slaholidayid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $slaholidayid;

    /*
     *  @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Slaplans",mappedBy="holidays", cascade={"ALL"})
     */
    private $plans;

    /*public function getPlans(){
        return $this->plans;
    }*/
}
```

Code to persist the entities:

```
$allholidays=array();
$holiday=$this->_em->getRepository('ZC\Entity\Slaholidays')->find($value);
$holiday=new ZC\Entity\Slaholidays();
//..sets holiday fields here
$this->_em->persist($holiday);
$allholidays[]=$holiday;

$slaplan->setHolidays($allholidays);
foreach ($slaplan->getHolidays() as $value) {
    $this->_em->persist($value);
}
$this->_em->persist($slaplan);
$this->_em->flush();
```

Comment: Posting more than necessary is better than posting less than necessary, but 90% of your entity declarations are useless, and maks the question hard to read and answer. I've removed irrelevant data, if you need it you can review it in the edit history.

Comment: Do you find a solution ? I am stuck with this weird problem too ..

Answer (score 0):

The are two issues in your code:

The first one: you are persisting each `Slaholiday` twice: first with

```
$this->_em->persist($holiday);
```

and second with

```
foreach ($slaplan->getHolidays() as $value) {
    $this->_em->persist($value);
}
```

There is no problem actually, as they are not actually persisted in the db until `flush` are called, but anyway, you don't need that `foreach`.

The reason why your join table is not updated is in `$slaplan->setHolidays` method. You are initializing `$slaplan->holidays` with `ArrayCollection` (which is right) and in `setHolidays` you set it to the input parameter (which is `$allholidays` `Array`, and this is not right).

So, the correct way to do that is to use [`add`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/common/2.0/api) method of the `ArrayCollection`

```
public function setHolidays($holidays)
{
    //$this->holidays->clear(); //clears the collection, uncomment if you need it
    foreach ($holidays as $holiday){
        $this->holidays->add($holiday);
    }
}
```

OR

```
public function addHolidays(ZC\Entity\Slaholiday $holiday)
{
    $this->holidays->add($holiday);
}

public function clearHolidays(){
    $this->holidays->clear();
}
//..and in the working script...//

//..the rest of the script
$this->_em->persist($holiday);
//$slaplan->clearHolidays(); //uncomment if you need your collection cleaned
$slaplan->addHOliday($holiday);
```

Comment: @JOHN          i changed the code and still get nothing , the join table isn't updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

Although Doctrine checks the owning side of an association for things that need to be persisted, it's always important to keep both sides of the association in sync.

My advise is to have get, add and remove (no set) methods at both sides, that look like this:

```
class Slaplans
{
    public function getHolidays()
    {
        return $this->holidays->toArray();
    }

    public function addHoliday(Slaholiday $holiday)
    {
        if (!$this->holidays->contains($holiday)) {
            $this->holidays->add($holiday);
            $holiday->addPlan($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeHoliday(Slaholiday $holiday)
    {
        if ($this->holidays->contains($holiday)) {
            $this->holidays->removeElement($holiday);
            $holiday->removePlan($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Do the same in `Slaplan`.

Now when you add a Slaholiday to a Slaplan, that Slaplan will also be added to the Slaholiday automatically. The same goes for removing.

So now you can do something like this:

```
$plan = $em->find('Slaplan', 1);

$holiday = new Slaholiday();
// set data on $holiday
// no need to persist $holiday, because you have a cascade={"ALL"} all on the association

$plan->addHoliday($holiday);
// no need to persist $plan, because it's managed by the entitymanager (unless you don't use change tracking policy "DEFERRED_IMPLICIT" (which is used by default))
$em->flush();
```

PS: Don't use `cascade` on both sides of the association. This will make things slower than necessary, and in some cases can lead to errors. If you create a Slaplan first, then add Slaholidays to it, keep the `cascade` in Slaplan and remove it from Slaholiday.